# Constructing my own HttpRequest object

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

Firstly let me state that **We are NOT using IIS** as our web server and do not intend to, so please no answers telling me to use IIs.  The application I am working on's strength is that it does not require an IIS Server to be installed.

Secondly, I am **not making a request** (I'm not a client), I am the server and am accepting the requests via a 3rd party embedded lightweight web server.

To keep things .NET based and so I don't have to reference my 3rd party web server library for dynamically loaded modules, I would like to use the `System.Web` namespace that IIS uses, as it's there in .NET.

What I am having problems with is that I cannot fully create my own `System.Web.HttpRequest` object, nor can I extend my own (it's sealed) to overcome the problem.

**How would I build a `System.Web.HttpRequest` object** that I can translate  information (such as headers, cookies, contentTypes, etc) from the 3rd party web server's handled requests to the .NET framework version?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using Katana or vNext for this?  This is EXACTLY what it gives you...servers completely decoupled from IIS if desired.  You're just reinventing an already extremely robust wheel.

Comment: Hmm...haven't heard of Katana yet, will have a look and see if it can do what I'm looking for.  Cheers.

Comment: What specific problems are you having when creating an `HttpRequest` instance? It has a public constructor and it has public properties that you can use to add cookies and headers to.

Comment: According to the documentation on the MSDN it does, but in practice it's a different situation.  You can't add to the Headers as the NameValueCollection object is set to Read Only, along with some other properties, such as the body content, etc.   I got caught on the same assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor `internal HttpRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)`. Pry it open using reflection. You then have to manufactore some other objects as well.

`HttpWorkerRequest` is made to be inherited from. No problem there. `HttpContext` has a constructor as well.

You might be forced to set other members using reflection as well. This scenario is barely supported.

ASP.NET MVC took the route of adding abstractions such as `HttpRequestBase`. Maybe you can migrate to use that.

Comment: Thanks, but that's just way to messy in creating a basic object.   I've just decided to make my own Interface/framework.   It's a shame as I would have loved to have used the .NET framework for consistency, but seems the developer they put on this project is a n00b.